why python doesn't calculate the result as per formula I provided
I am working on python, what is wrong with the following code:
try:
    x, y = input("fraction: ").split("/")
    result = int(f"{x}* 100/{y}%")
    if result <= 1:
        print("E")
    elif result >= 99:
        print("F")
    else:
        print(result)
except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
    print(x, y)

I expected the code to calculate the result and output the %, but it only give me the same input as output

Your input is a string. You need to cast the parts to int()

Pl check my answer as well

Print the error message to see the reason:
try:
    x, y = input("fraction: ").split("/")
    result = int(f"{x}* 100/{y}%")
    if result <= 1:
        print("E")
    elif result >= 99:
        print("F")
    else:
        print(result)
except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError) as e:
    print(type(e), e)  # new line
    print(x, y)

output:
fraction: 3/4
<class 'ValueError'> invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3* 100/4%'
3 4

you need to change the:
result = int(f"{x}* 100/{y}%")

to
result = int(x) * 100 / int(y)


Exactly.  int doesn't know how to evaluate formulas, only pure numbers.

Result is added inside f-string and a character '%' is added. Now the result will be considered as a string which can't be compared with any number.
try:
    x, y = (int(x) for x in (input("fraction: ").split("/")))
   
    result = x*100/y
    if result <= 1:
        print("E")
    elif result >= 99:
        print("F")
    else:
        print(f'{result} %')
except (ValueError, ZeroDivisionError):
    print(x, y)

